# Cannot set Nullable DateTime property

Tags: vb.net, nullable

I have the following code which I am trying to get data from the database for a Nullable DateTime Field in SQL Server -

```
 If dr("SendDate") Is DBNull.Value Then
      ctrl_prov_dtl.SelectedDateSendDate = DirectCast(Nothing, System.Nullable(Of DateTime))
 Else
      ctrl_prov_dtl.SelectedDateSendDate = dr("SendDate")
 End If
```

This is calling the following Public Property

```
Public Property SelectedDateSendDate() As Nullable(Of DateTime)
    Get
        Dim myDateTime As DateTime

        If (DateTime.TryParse(calSendDate.Text, myDateTime)) Then
            Return calSendDate.Text
        Else
            Return "01/01/1900"
        End If
    End Get
    Set(value As Nullable(Of DateTime))
       calSendDate.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I keep getting the following error **Nullable object must have a value.**

I am really confused because I am setting the value to a **Nullable(Of DateTime)**

Comment: Does this happen when the calSenddate is set or when it hits you return 01/01/1900? if it is the second return why not just return DateTime.MinValue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely because you are trying to set the text value of `calSendDate` to `value` regardless if it's null or not.

Instead, change your property setter to this:

```
Set(value As Nullable(Of DateTime))
   If value.HasValue Then
       calSendDate.Text = value
   Else
       calSendDate.Text = Nothing
   End If
End Set
```

**Additional advice:**

If your project is .NET 3.5 or above and references *System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll*, change your first block of code to this instead:

```
ctrl_prov_dtl.SelectedDateSendDate = dr.Field(Of DateTime?)("SendDate")
```

Also, your property getter never returns the parsed `myDateTime` value. And returning 1/1/1900 as the fallback value on a nullable type feels very wrong to me.

Comment: Same error InvalidOperationException was caught - Nullable object must have a value.

Comment: @Moojjoo Show the complete stack trace in your message please.

Comment: No need you got it Crono ----   If value.HasValue Then
       calSendDate.Text = value
   Else
       calSendDate.Text = Nothing
   End If